# Correction in this simple regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regular expressions and the one that i have written might be a very simple one but donot know where I am wrong.

```
@"^([a-zA-Z._]+)@([\d]+)"
```

This RE is for the following string:

```
somename@somenumber
```

Now i am trying to retrieve the somename and somenumber. This is what i did:

```
ac.name = m.Groups[0].Value;
ac.number = m.Groups[1].Value;
```

Here ac.name reads the **complete string**, and ac.number reads **somenumber**. Where am I wrong in ac.name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex is [correct](http://regexr.com?31njf). I think your mistake is in somewhere else. You seem to use C#. So, you should think about the [regex usage in the language](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match).

Looking to [the code sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx#remarksToggle) in MSDN, you need to use **1-based** indexes while accessing `Groups` instead of zero-based (as also Kent [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11791661/471214)). So, use this:

```
String name   = m.Groups[1].Value;
String number = m.Groups[2].Value;
```

Comment: Ok, then please retag your question with C# also.

Answer (score 2):

i guess the regex is correct, the problem is, you get the ac.name not from group 1 but group(0), which is the whole string. try this:

```
ac.name = m.Groups[1].Value;
ac.number = m.Groups[2].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

use this regex `(\w+)@(\d+([.,]\d+)?)`

`Groups[1]` will be contain name

`Groups[2]` will be contain number

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move the `+` into the capture group:

```
@"^([a-zA-Z._]+)@([\d]+)"
```

Comment: what is the language? can you share an actual example?

Comment: Your problem might be that the '.' matches all (even though as far as I remember it should not have a special meaning inside []. at least in ruby it doesn't) try escaping it like this: '\.'

Answer (score 0):

If this is C#, try without the ^

```
([a-zA-Z\._]+)@([\d]+)
```

I just tried it out and it groups properly

Update: escaped the .

If you want only one match (and hence the ^ in original expression), use `.Match` instead of `.Matches` method. See [MSDN documentation on Regular Expression Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).